# Kafka consumer rebalance occurs even if there is no message to consume

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have been seeing so many kafka consumer rebalances even if the thread is consuming nothing.I would expect the consumer not to rebalance in this scenario.
Here is the sample code.

```
import argparse
from kafka.coordinator.assignors.range import RangePartitionAssignor
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import time
import sys
import logging
from kafka.consumer.subscription_state import ConsumerRebalanceListener

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)


def get_config(args):
    config = {
        'bootstrap_servers': args.host,
        'group_id': args.group,
        'key_deserializer': lambda msg: msg,
        'value_deserializer': lambda msg: msg,
        'partition_assignment_strategy': [RangePartitionAssignor],
        'max_poll_records': args.records,
        'auto_offset_reset': args.offset,
        # 'max_poll_interval_ms': 300000,
        # 'connections_max_idle_ms': 8 * 60 * 1000
    }
    return config


def start_consumer(args):
    config = get_config(args)
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(**config)
    consumer.subscribe([args.topic],
                       listener=RepartitionListener(None))
    for record in consumer:
        print record.offset, record.partition
        time.sleep(int(args.delay) / 1000.0)



class RepartitionListener(ConsumerRebalanceListener):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def on_partitions_revoked(self, revoked):
        print("partition revoked ")
        for tp in revoked:
            try:
                print("[{}] revoked topic = {} partition = {}".format(time.strftime("%c"),
                                                                      tp.topic, tp.partition))
                partition_key = "{}_{}".format(tp.topic, str(tp.partition))

            except Exception as e:
                print("Got exception partition_key = {} {}".
                      format(tp, e.message))

    def on_partitions_assigned(self, assigned):
        pass


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Tool to test consumer group with delay')
    named_args = parser.add_argument_group('snamed arguments')
    named_args.add_argument('-g', '--group', help='group id for the consumer',
                            required=True)
    named_args.add_argument('-r', '--records', help='num records to consume',
                            required=True)
    named_args.add_argument('-k', '--topic', help='kafka topic', required=True)
    named_args.add_argument('-d', '--delay', help='add process delay in ms', required=True)
    named_args.add_argument('-s', '--host', help='Kafka host format host:port', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--offset',
                        default='latest',
                        help='offset to read from earliest/latest')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args
    start_consumer(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

1. How to avoid the rebalance trigger? From the logs I am seeing heartbeat is failing, But I am expecting the heartbeat to be continued even if there is no messages over a period of time greater than `session.time.out.ms`.

> 2019-02-27 20:39:43,281 - kafka.coordinator - WARNING - Heartbeat session expired, marking coordinator dead

Comment: which version of consumer client are you using? could be [this](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1418)?

Comment: I am using 1.4.4 python client.

Comment: There was a bug in the client. I tried the workaround as suggested here. https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1418